# Is there a funny margin somewhere?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm trying to create my own graph control, but I'm having some problems with the x-lines.

I've created a new control and added it to a empty WP7 project. The control has a `StackPanel` with the name `Canvas` and `Height` and `Width` set to 400.

Just to get started i written some code to get a look:

```
            double yStepping = Canvas.Height/5;
            double y = 0;

            // generate x lines
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                y += 10;

                Line l = new Line()
                {
                    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
                    StrokeThickness = 2,

                    X1 = 10,
                    Y1 = y,

                    X2 = 100,
                    Y2 = y
                };

                Canvas.Children.Add(l);
            }
```

I would think this creates evenly spaced lines but it does not. for each line the spacing grows. Why is that?

Comment: @usr the spacing should be 10 between each line and increase by 10 for each line. 0, 10, 20, 30. But im getting 0, 10, 22, 34 (or something) visually :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack panel stacks your lines. Each line has a height of at least two because of its stroke thickness. In addition, the Y-value of each line adds to its height (more precisely: to its bounding box from which the height is derived).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Snoop for WPF equivelent for Silverlight e.g. [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/) to examine the visual tree and see which element(s) increase the width & height vs the inner control or even if that control has the wrong settings due to an unexpected binding.